# Paypal posting error in magento order creation programatically

Tags: php, magento, paypal, ionic-framework, paypal-sandbox

i am developing hybrid mobile application for magento site. Now i need to create orders programatically. I am able to integrate paypal and getting paypal success response. once i got paypal response am posting data to magento. here am getting error as

```
Uncaught exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'PayPal gateway has rejected request. 
Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token).' in public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php:1062
```

Below is my order creation code.

```
<?php

// Mage Path
require_once( dirname(__FILE__).'/../app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
// Initialize Magento ...
Mage::app("default");

$id=11; // get Customer Id
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($id);

$transaction = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
$reservedOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType('order')->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);

$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->setIncrementId($reservedOrderId)
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteId(0)
->setGlobal_currency_code('USD')
->setBase_currency_code('USD')
->setStore_currency_code('USD')
->setOrder_currency_code('USD');
//Set your store currency USD or any other

// set Customer data
$order->setCustomer_email($customer->getEmail())
->setCustomerFirstname($customer->getFirstname())
->setCustomerLastname($customer->getLastname())
->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId())
->setCustomer_is_guest(0)
->setCustomer($customer);

// set Billing Address
$billing = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress();
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_BILLING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultBilling())
->setCustomer_address_id($billing->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($billing->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($billing->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($billing->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($billing->getLastname())
->setSuffix($billing->getSuffix())
->setCompany($billing->getCompany())
->setStreet($billing->getStreet())
->setCity($billing->getCity())
->setCountry_id($billing->getCountryId())
->setRegion($billing->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($billing->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($billing->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($billing->getTelephone())
->setFax($billing->getFax());
$order->setBillingAddress($billingAddress);

$shipping = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress();
$shippingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setAddressType(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address::TYPE_SHIPPING)
->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
->setCustomerAddressId($customer->getDefaultShipping())
->setCustomer_address_id($shipping->getEntityId())
->setPrefix($shipping->getPrefix())
->setFirstname($shipping->getFirstname())
->setMiddlename($shipping->getMiddlename())
->setLastname($shipping->getLastname())
->setSuffix($shipping->getSuffix())
->setCompany($shipping->getCompany())
->setStreet($shipping->getStreet())
->setCity($shipping->getCity())
->setCountry_id($shipping->getCountryId())
->setRegion($shipping->getRegion())
->setRegion_id($shipping->getRegionId())
->setPostcode($shipping->getPostcode())
->setTelephone($shipping->getTelephone())
->setFax($shipping->getFax());

$order->setShippingAddress($shippingAddress)
->setShipping_method('flatrate_flatrate');
/*->setShippingDescription($this->getCarrierName('flatrate'));*/
/*some error i am getting here need to solve further*/

//you can set your payment method name here as per your need
$orderPayment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setCustomerPaymentId("PAY-9G20599927263253EK6BC2SA")
->setMethod('paypal_express')
->setPo_number('8EV04718DA563240K');
$order->setPayment($orderPayment);

// let say, we have 2 products
//check that your products exists
//need to add code for configurable products if any
$subTotal = 0;
$products = array(
    '1' => array(
    'qty' => 2
    ));

foreach ($products as $productId=>$product) {
//$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getIdBySku('property_415682');

if ($id) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
}

$rowTotal = $_product->getPrice() * $product['qty'];
$orderItem = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
->setStoreId($storeId)
->setQuoteItemId(0)
->setQuoteParentItemId(NULL)
->setProductId($productId)
->setProductType($_product->getTypeId())
->setQtyBackordered(NULL)
->setTotalQtyOrdered($product['rqty'])
->setQtyOrdered($product['qty'])
->setName($_product->getName())
->setSku($_product->getSku())
->setPrice($_product->getPrice())
->setBasePrice($_product->getPrice())
->setOriginalPrice($_product->getPrice())
->setRowTotal($rowTotal)
->setBaseRowTotal($rowTotal);

$subTotal += $rowTotal;
$order->addItem($orderItem);
}

$order->setSubtotal($subTotal)
->setBaseSubtotal($subTotal)
->setGrandTotal($subTotal)
->setBaseGrandTotal($subTotal);

$transaction->addObject($order);
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'place'));
$transaction->addCommitCallback(array($order, 'save'));
$transaction->save();
```

Reference i followed is

```
http://pragneshkaria.com/programmatically-create-order-in-magento/
```

For paypal payment integration i used this plugin

```
 https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin
```

I'm new to magento and ionic app development so Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But do you expect to charge real PayPal account with this code? Magento on each model save may execute observers which may connect to the real paypal gateway, and PayPal of course require some sort of authentication token. If you want to just import old data you should go through more plain queries approach.

Comment: @PawelDubiel i tried with plain queries but i'm facing difficulties in that too. can you please share any example or references to create orders using DB queries.

Answer (score 0):

If this **one off** **import** and you don't want charge customers, and you are ready to use hacky solutions, then you can try to modify

`_placeOrder` method at

*`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php`* and try comment out

```
$api->callDoExpressCheckoutPayment();
```

This function above is triggering the whole process.

---

```
/**
 * Place an order with authorization or capture action
 *
 * @param Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment $payment
 * @param float $amount
 * @return Mage_Paypal_Model_Express
 */
protected function _placeOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment $payment, $amount)
{
    $order = $payment->getOrder();

    // prepare api call
    $token = $payment->getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_TOKEN);
    $api = $this->_pro->getApi()
        ->setToken($token)
        ->setPayerId($payment->
            getAdditionalInformation(Mage_Paypal_Model_Express_Checkout::PAYMENT_INFO_TRANSPORT_PAYER_ID))
        ->setAmount($amount)
        ->setPaymentAction($this->_pro->getConfig()->paymentAction)
        ->setNotifyUrl(Mage::getUrl('paypal/ipn/'))
        ->setInvNum($order->getIncrementId())
        ->setCurrencyCode($order->getBaseCurrencyCode())
        ->setPaypalCart(Mage::getModel('paypal/cart', array($order)))
        ->setIsLineItemsEnabled($this->_pro->getConfig()->lineItemsEnabled);

    // COMMENT LINE BELOW
    $api->callDoExpressCheckoutPayment();

    $this->_importToPayment($api, $payment);
    return $this;
}
```

If you need to do it on a daily basis, you can look into "monkey patching" for PHP and override this method on a fly without modifying the file.

You could also probably extend this extension or override just *`app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express.php`* by placing it into local Magento directory and then add extra logic to _placeOrder  ( how to override  https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14024897 )

---

Another solution could be creating custom payment method in Magento ( http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/  ) with custom payment code which you will use instead of paypal_express. After that, you could replace fields in the database from your custom method name to paypal_express.

Also you can create a new payment method with the custom name like "my_paypal_express" and use it instead of paypal_express.

To be honest, I am not very happy with these solutions listed above, but they may help you a bit.